# Is there any way to integrate firebase analytics into an expo react-native app without detaching?

Tags: firebase, react-native, expo, firebase-analytics

I've been struggling to find a way to integrate firebase analytics into an app I've built with react native and expo. All available solutions require detaching, but I don't want that. So ss there any way to integrate firebase analytics into an expo react-native app without detaching?

Comment: does anyone know if this is available yet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's currently not possible without detaching, but it seems that it's being worked on and is on the horizon.

Take a look at this: [What’s New in Expo-Firebase rc.5 - TL;DR: It’s not in the client yet](https://blog.expo.io/whats-new-in-expo-firebase-rc-5-dd6e789274b0)

Comment: Thanks for that. I was looking at earlier posts by Evan saying that they're working on support for it, but this definitely answered my question.