# Can You Use Firebase Analytics With Expo React Native Web App?

Tags: firebase, react-native, expo, firebase-analytics, react-native-firebase

I have been reading all through the documentation and through all of the other StackOverflow posts and am still not entirely sure if a react native expo app can have firebase analytics included or not.

I am not sure if I am supposed to use:

```
import * as Analytics from 'expo-firebase-analytics';
```

or

```
import analytics from "@react-native-firebase/analytics";
```

or if I am supposed to use `googleServicesFile` but I am using a web app so I don't have the file to download to add to the .pilist

I read this post and it doesn't look like it is possible: [Is there any way to integrate firebase analytics into an expo react-native app without detaching?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54021264/is-there-any-way-to-integrate-firebase-analytics-into-an-expo-react-native-app-w)

but I also am reading through the expo documentation and it looks like it is possible: https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/firebase-analytics/#expo-client-limitations--configuration

I am either getting errors thrown or no response when I write the events. So needless to say I am super confused. Any help would be appreciated.